# How to actually block youtube app in router?

Tags: networking, router, youtube, blocking, mobile-phone

I wanted to block youtube for my lazy brother who is addicted to. I tried map IPs that youtube app access, and block each. But Google servers is like a octopus
In my router i think i have to block a lot of DNS by with a aleatory numbers that changes all day, and block all port like []:8338; []:8339; []:8339.

Comment: If you can edit his hosts file, add youtube.com to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Ever got it done? I also need this...

Answer (score -2):

You would need something like a web security appliance for that. Filters websites based on policies.

You could also edit the hosts file on his pc to point youtube.com to a loopback address, which will of course return nothing.

Or you can host your own dns server, change the dhcp server to point to yours first and redirect youtube.com to 127.0.0.1 and call it a day. Have dns forward all other requests to 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8